# Injecting generic class with Dagger

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I have an abstract base class in my project

```
public abstract class BaseActivity<T extends BasePresenter<? extends IBaseView>> implements IBaseView{
```

Into which I try to inject a generic class like this:

```
@Inject protected T mPresenter;
```

Is there any way to make dagger work with such a generic injection? Dagger generates code like:

```
public final class BaseActivity$$InjectAdapter extends Binding<BaseActivity>
implements MembersInjector<BaseActivity> {
    private Binding<T> mPresenter;
}
```

And then fails because "T cannot be resolved to a type". Is there any way to make it generate a

```
Binding<SomethingExtendingBasePresenter> mPresenter
```

in such case?

Comment: Your types are very odd. Why is an `Activity` extending an interface for a `View`?

Comment: The Activity is implementing a BaseView interface, it's View from Model-View-Presenter pattern, not View as in android.view.View

Comment: In that case, since your Activity is a presenter it probably shouldn't also be a View.

Comment: The Activity isn't a Presenter - it just implmenets the View interface. So: Presenter (represented by a fooPresenter class) works on the IFooView interface, that's implemented by a fooActivity class. I want to inject a class that's a subclass of the BasePresenter into a class that's a subclass oh BaseActivity, based on the generic type T. The code above works in RoboGuice, but I can't get it to work in Dagger.

Comment: Can you post your module?

Comment: Why is the `View` interface not implemented by the `android.view.View`?

Comment: @NelsonOsacky it could be - the whole point of using an interface is that it can be implemented by whatever best suits the situation, since the logic stays untouched in the presenter. Currently I mostly use fragments, but sometimes it's an Activity or a View.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of is to create a new class that extends your generic. One for each type you are interested in.

```
public class Foo extends BaseActivity<SomethingExtendingBasePresenter> {
}

@Inject
Foo mFoo;
```